# R Studio unresponsive, won't quit or close tabs, menus unresponsive

Tags: r, windows-10, rstudio

My R Studio is completely frozen.  None of the menus work (items are unresponsive when clicking), I can't close any tabs, and even after a shutdown and killing the application in Windows 10, every time I restart R it is still in the same frozen state and all the tabs are still open.

I have tried the suggestion to reset R Studio:

```
You can open an Explorer window into the RStudio-Desktop directory by typing the following command into Start -> Run:

For Windows 7, 8 and 10:

%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop
You can then rename this directory to backup-rstudio-desktop and send it with your support request.
```

Renaming this folder did nothing to help. I'm on Windows 10, R is latest version 4.0.2.

Comment: You probably have workspace saving enabled and RStudio loads the data that crashed your session. I disabled that feature years ago and can't remember how the file would be called, but try to find an `.RData` file in the directory you defined as your working directory that looks like auto-save data and change the ending to something like `.tmp` and try to start RStudio. You may also delete that file but then it's gone, though :)

Comment: Thanks!  Where would .RData file be located?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what my working directory is set to.

Comment: Hm, normally it should be "My documents" or in some sub-folder; you could use windows search for "*.RData", and the newest file should be the culprit.

Comment: Also consider this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start